# Should I free the pointer returned by setlocale?

Tags: c, linux, macos, valgrind, setlocale

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ret = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    // should I free 'ret' ???
    // free(ret);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried both on Linux and OS X 10.10, on Linux, I must not call 'free', but on OS X, if I do not call 'free', valgrind complains a memory leak.

```
==62032== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==62032== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==62032== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==62032== Command: ./a.out
==62032== 
--62032-- ./a.out:
--62032-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
==62032== 
==62032== HEAP SUMMARY:
==62032==     in use at exit: 129,789 bytes in 436 blocks
==62032==   total heap usage: 519 allocs, 83 frees, 147,421 bytes allocated
==62032== 
==62032== 231 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 63 of 91
==62032==    at 0x10000859B: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==62032==    by 0x1001E68C8: currentlocale (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62032==    by 0x100000F6B: main (in ./a.out)
==62032== 
==62032== LEAK SUMMARY:
==62032==    definitely lost: 231 bytes in 1 blocks
==62032==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==62032==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==62032==    still reachable: 94,869 bytes in 10 blocks
==62032==         suppressed: 34,689 bytes in 425 blocks
==62032== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==62032== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==62032== 
==62032== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==62032== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 17)
```

So, 
in Linux, if I call 'free', it will crash.
in OS X, if I do not call 'free', it has a memory leak.

Comment: Have you tried that with `free()` ??

Comment: yes ideally you should free that....

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S, my confusion is that the behavior is different between linux and os x.

Comment: @noinput Maybe. A suggestion you can try with `free()`. then post that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should **not** `free` the string that you get. According to the C11 standard:

> 7.11.1.1 The `setlocale` function
>
> The pointer to string returned by the
>   `setlocale`
>   function is such that a subsequent call
>   with that string value and its associated category will restore that part of the program’s
>   locale. **The string pointed to shall not be modified by the program,** but may be
>   overwritten by a subsequent call to the
>   `setlocale`
>   function

Additionally, the Linux [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) say:

> This string may be allocated in
>          static storage.

which would result in your program crashing if you tried to `free` it.

It looks like the Linux implementation uses static storage, but the OSX one uses `malloc`. Regardless of what's going on under the hood, you **should not modify it** because the standard disallows you from doing so --- the fact that it would be safe on OSX is an implementation quirk you should ignore. Valgrind is essentially giving you a false positive here.