# Why does running Valgrind on bash scripts report memory leaks?

Tags: c++, bash, memory-leaks, valgrind

I had a C++ program that I was running within a bash script, and I wanted to see if the program was leaking memory, so I did `valgrind ./doTheThing.sh` and it reported 12 bytes of memory leaked. I figured my program wasn't structured well, so I made some changes, tried again, and still the same 12 bytes of memory were being leaked. After I tried enough different things to make the C++ program not leak memory and getting the *exact same leak,* I tried making the program malloc 100,000 bytes and then exit and...12 bytes of memory leaked. Then I ran the program on its own outside of the script and the memory leaks showed up in ways that actually made sense.

So the problem was running valgrind on a bash script. Is this because valgrind wasn't meant to be used on bash scripts and glitches in a way that makes it *look* like it leaks 12 bytes of memory? Or do bash scripts inherently leak 12 bytes of memory every time they run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301576/how-do-i-tell-valgrind-to-memcheck-forked-processes

Comment: Does it matter? If the bytes are leaked but the program is shutting down anyway, it doesn't really matter. Memory leaks only really matter for long running programs. It's not like leaks persist across program invocations.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Not particularly in this instance, but I'm asking so I can learn more about how both valgrind and memory allocation works

Comment: Aren't you running Valgrind on bash rather than your program now?

Comment: @thatotherguy yeah, my question is about why bash reports 12 bytes of memory leak every time it runs

Comment: There appears to be some further investigation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553905/is-bash-leaking-memory